# How to best share entity classes/DAOs across multiple PUs?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, architecture

Let's take a basic example, say we have an entity class

```
@Entity
public class User {
}
```

and a DAO for dealing with the data:

```
public interface UserDao {
    @Transactional
    public void changeUser(User user);
}

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void changeUser(User user) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

We have a main Maven Project that contains plenty other sub-projects, that we use for building multiple application (WARs, JARs etc.). Our framework of choice is Spring.

Each and every application needs the above entity / DAO and there are no per application customizations needed, everything remains the same.
Every application has its own data source / persistence unit / transaction manager.

How can one best reuse the above entity / DAO across multiple applications? The entities need to be persisted in the application's database and we'd also need to reuse the app's transaction manager.

What did you do in similar situations?

Comment: Is the datasource same for each of these applications ?

Comment: @Sashi No. Every app has its own data source with a different database behind it.

Answer (score 1):

I would create separate Maven module that would contain entities and DAOs (you can even create two modules - one for entities and one for DAOs).

This module would be added as a dependency to any other application module (EJB or WAR modules), which needs DB layer. In Spring configuration you should properly define injection rules for datasource, persistence context, transaction manager, etc. In this way you would have common code with different configuration.

Comment: The common entities and DAOs are already part of a maven module persistence-common. How would you go about the Spring configuration? That seems to be where it gets a bit tricky.

Comment: persistence-common should not have Spring context files, each EAR or EJB or WAR module should have its own context file with persistence configuration - datasource plus transaction manager plus JPA Template (if you want to use it). This file should be imported into main spring context file. Obviously each of these modules needs also persistence.xml file

Comment: I'm trying it the way you proposed, the war file gets generated correctly but whwn I try to launch the server and deploy the project, i get this error in the tomcat logs: "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myproject.commons.mydao.SuperEntityDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}" Any idean on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, modularizing classes is the easy part; automating configuration look-up/loading is the tricky part.

I suppose one could create an `applicationContext.xml` for each module (listing beans, controllers etc. in it) and use the multiple configuration support to load them. But since obviously we can't name all XML files the same I would suggest the following:

Main project's `web.xml`:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:auto-appctx-*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

And a Maven/Ant script that would timestamp the XML file during packaging of each module/JAR like this:

```
    <target name="copy-unique-appctx">
        <timestamp/>
        <copy src="src/resource/applicationContext.xml"
            dest="build/classes/auto-appctx-${timestamp}.xml"/>
    </target>
```

Note that this Ant target is typed "by memory" which is sketchy at the moment, and needs to be corrected (if the idea actually works).

Comment: Actually this is not required. Each and every app has a main Maven module, so we have a custom main resource (for instance web.xml) for each app where we can define what gets loaded and what not.
There is also a parent context and a persistence unit (META-INF/persistence.xml) on a per app basis, also part of this main module.
The first problem one runs into is getting the entities from a different module (jar) registered... And it's not the end of it.

Comment: Please check [this article](http://www.harezmi.com.tr/auto-scanning-jpa-entities/?lang=en) and [this one](http://hibernatebp.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-auto-scan-jpa-entities-using.html). The idea is to keep `persistence.xml` in each JAR but to be able to automatically "find them" in an application.